# Error with tensorflow.js and reactjs only on mobile browsers

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, webgl, object-detection-api

I created an object detection model that I use on my react app and on desktop it works perfectly but when tried on mobile browsers getting the following error.
Error: Requested texture size [4988x4989] greater than WebGL maximum on this browser / GPU [4096x4096].

[image: Error while running prediction on mobile browser]

Comment: Have you tried all the browsers e.g Chrome, Firefox, etc? Do you receive errors on all the browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much you can do. This is the limitation of the browser and on the phone browser, the WebGL does not have much memory available.

You can read more about this issue raised in [Tensorflowjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/689#issuecomment-503590183).

Answer (score 0):

More than 2 years, but anyway...

You shoud be able to de-scale (lower the resolution) of the input before passing it to the object detector.